# Why does jQuery .height() not work in firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I console.log(titleHeight); I get 0 in firefox but the correct height in chrome.. Any idea why?

```
$('.projects__col').each(function() {
    const _this = $(this);
    let titleHeight = title.height();
    console.log(titleHeight); // gives me the correct height in Chrome but 0 in firefox

    _this.click(function () {

        _this.css({
            'transform': `translateY(-${titleHeight}px)`,
            '-o-transform': `translateY(-${titleHeight}px)`,
            '-moz-transform': `translateY(-${titleHeight}px)`,
            '-webkit-transform': `translateY(-${titleHeight}px)`,
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: because your image  is not yet loaded, therefore the height is 0 use jQuery(window).load(function(){....})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this same code after:  const _this = $(this);

```
  $(this)
.load(function() {
    //$('#result1').text('Image is loaded!');   
    let titleHeight = title.height();
    console.log(titleHeight);
})
.error(function() {
    $('#result1').text('Image is not loaded!');
});
```